# Extracting the data from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe having data in each row like below

```
Joel Thompson / Tracy K. Smith</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
  <p>New work (World Premiere–New York Philharmonic Commission)
```

How would I filter this so I can get results to work with like this:

```
   name : Joel Thompson, Tracy K. Smith
   information : New work (World Premiere–New York Philharmonic Commission)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use the split function for string variables. You can do this this way :

```
#Get your row in a string variable text
text = "Joel Thompson / Tracy K. Smith</h2></div><div><p>New work (World Premiere–New York Philharmonic Commission)"

#Extracting the name
Names_string = text.split("</h2>")[0]
Names_list = Names_string.split(" / ")

#Extracting information
Information = text.split("<p>")[-1]

result = {
    "name" : Names_list,
    'information' : Information
}

print(result)
```

It will display this :

> {'name': ['Joel Thompson', 'Tracy K. Smith'], 'information': 'New work (World Premiere–New York Philharmonic Commission)'}

You should make it a function this way :

```
def getDictFromRow(text):
    #Extracting the name
    Names_string = text.split("</h2>")[0]
    Names_list = Names_string.split(" / ")

    #Extracting information
    Information = text.split("<p>")[-1]

    result = {
        "name" : Names_list,
        'information' : Information
    }
    return result

print(getDictFromRow("Joel Thompson / Tracy K. Smith</h2></div><div><p>New work (World Premiere–New York Philharmonic Commission)"))
```